# Call https from nodejs - where to place the digital cer file?

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, certificate

I have an application, running on RedHat, and it makes https calls to an external address. 
When I issue the wget command to the external address, it works fine. But the same running inside the application fails due to SSL hanshake issues.
The digitial certificate file is located in /etc/ssl/certs

Kind regards

Savio

Comment: What exactly are you using, NodeJS with Express? Are you trying to request a route from within another route? Do you have any code that is particularly giving you trouble? Also, if you are requesting an external address from within Node, which module are you using? (https, request, etc..)

Comment: [This](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback) is typically how you make requests using HTTPS within Node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from the [Node API reference](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback):

```
const https = require('https');

https.get('https://encrypted.google.com/', (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });

}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
```

Or you can use the [request module](https://github.com/request/request):

```
const request = require("request");

request.get('https://google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(body);
});
```